# compare two csv files and append the result in a new column

Tags: text-processing

I have two csv files the current file New.csv and the previous version Old.csv. Here is what they look like:

old.csv

```
name,age,lastname,film,song,mother,fadher,col0,col1,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,a,b,z,t
jay,23,,stgh,tt,,,,,,,,,,,
Ann,32,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Chris,43,titanic,hi,,,,,,,
```

new.csv

```
name,age,lastname,film,song,mother,fadher,col0,col1,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,a,b,z,t
jay,23,,stgh,tt,,,,,,,,,,,
alex,22,,hello,,,,,,,,,,,jed,,,
```

I want to compare them using linux commands and found a result like this one:

```
status,name,age,lastname,film,song,mother,fadher,col0,col1,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,a,b,z,t
Common,jay,23,,stgh,tt,,,,,,,,,,,
New,alex,22,,hello,,,,,,,,,,,jed,,,
Old,Ann,32,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Old,Chris,43,titanic,hi,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Both input files have too few data fields compared to the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` one way:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && NR>1{seen[$0]++; next} 
     NR==1{ print "Status," $0}
     FNR!=1{print ($0 in seen)?"Common," $0:"New," $0;delete seen[$0];}
END{for (x in seen) print "Old," x}' old.csv new.csv
```

The output:

```
Status,name,age,lastname,film,song,mother,fadher,col0,col1,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,a,b,z,t
Common,jay,23,,stgh,tt,,,,,,,,,,,
New,alex,22,,hello,,,,,,,,,,,jed,,,
Old,Chris,43,titanic,hi,,,,,,,
Old,Ann,32,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```